# Indexing and Page Ranking Issues

Tags: seo, google, ranking

Hi all
I am on the first page of google for keywords concerned with MOVING, however i cant seem to break the carpet cleaning rankings. I have made changes and additions which havent been indexed yet. Should i wait for the run or please please can someone give me pointers on the carpet cleaning indexing.

Also i have 53pages submitted and only 38 indexed, where could the problem be. Is there software to check indexing hiccups .

Thanks.

Comment: Be patient. Google takes a long time to index new sites.

Answer (score 2):

Be Patient. Google can take a long time initially to index new sites.

1) Create a Sitemap to help the Google Crawler bots out and store it in your root directory as sitemap.xml. I recommend using [Sitemap Writer Pro](http://www.sitemapwriter.com/download.html?name=download.php) . It will automatically scan all your files on your domain for you and create an XML Sitemap for Google's bots and an HTML Sitemap for you w/ links and page descriptions which users will find useful as well! It's great tool, especially if you have 50+ pages! It beats listing them all manually!

2) Look at what your top competitors are doing and mimick their website structure and content.

3) Run Keyword Analytics to see what people search for.

4) Find a niche market that works for your product - IE: Carpet Installation for Atlanta, GA

5) Associate your business with a Twitter, Facebook, and Places account

6) Add backlinking

7) Read a book on SEO lol

What is the website written in? Is it a Wordpress site? Sometimes you can get penalized for duplicate info if your wordpress sites aren't indexed correctly. Make sure none of the pages have duplicate info that you are trying to index. Google automatically ignores duplicate pages now.